# Extjs 6 Windows Resize, Detect Browser Events

Tags: extjs

onWindowResize is not working any more on 6.2 extjs how can i detect the event of any browser when maximize or change window happenso the panel can adjust automatically to the new windows width.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a series of global events that fire through the `Ext` object, one of which is the `resize` event:

`Ext.on('resize', function() { console.log('go'); });`

Comment: Tanks for answer it help, i having and issue when i updateLayout it remove css.

Comment: I can't really respond to that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function(){
   me.setWidth(Ext.getBody().getWidth()-40);
   me.setHeight(Ext.getBody().getHeight()-20);
  });
```

Comment: where, var me = this;